# Left join producing row with values and another with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

First let me give some context. Suppose I have tasks that have a state: complete or incomplete. The tasks can be either incomplete and then complete, or immediately completed. These states are saved. I want to know whether a task went through that incomplete state or not.

```
/* Two possible states for a task, marked by a bit */
CREATE TABLE state (ID int unique not null, iscomplete bit not null);
INSERT INTO state (ID, iscomplete)
    VALUES (1, 0), (2, 1);

/* Three tasks, 2nd yet incomplete, 1 and 3 complete */
CREATE TABLE task (ID int unique not null, curr_state int not null);
INSERT INTO task (ID, curr_state)
    VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4);

/* All states for tasks, task 1 has had an incomplete state, 3 has not */
CREATE TABLE curr_state (ID int unique not null, task int not null, state int not null);
INSERT INTO curr_state (ID, task, state)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 3, 2);

STATE:              TASK:               CURR_STATE:
ID  | IsComplete    ID  | Curr_state    ID  | Task  | State
----+-----------    ----+-----------    ----+-------+-------
 1  | 0 (False)     1   |     2         1   |   1   |   1
 2  | 1 (True)      2   |     3         2   |   1   |   2
                    3   |     4         3   |   2   |   1
                                        4   |   3   |   2
```

With this query I'm able to get almost what I want, which is all complete cases with either the incomplete state or a `NULL` in `Through`.

```
SELECT t.ID as Task, s.iscomplete as Complete, st.ID as Through

/* Get finished tasks */
FROM task t
JOIN curr_state c
ON t.curr_state = c.ID
JOIN state s
ON c.state = s.ID

/* JOIN to unfinished states */
LEFT JOIN curr_state cs
ON t.ID = cs.task
LEFT JOIN state st
ON cs.state = st.ID and st.iscomplete = 0

WHERE s.iscomplete = 1

-------- RESULT ---------

Task | Complete | Through
 1       true        1
 1       true      (null)
 3       true      (null)

-------- DESIRED --------

Task | Complete | Through
 1       true        1
 3       true      (null)
```

The only problem is that now the first task is there twice, first with the incomplete state and then with `NULL`. How could this be avoided?

Fiddle me [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27548/7).

#### Edit:

The first `LEFT JOIN` is redundant and can be swapped to a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: It would help your question to also show the starting data in table form.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Noted and edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.ID as Task, s.iscomplete as Complete, through.ID as Through

/* Get finished tasks */
FROM task t
JOIN curr_state c ON t.curr_state = c.ID
JOIN state s ON c.state = s.ID

/* JOIN to unfinished states */
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT st.ID
   FROM curr_state cs
   JOIN state st ON cs.state = st.ID 
   WHERE st.iscomplete = 0 AND cs.task = t.ID
) AS through

WHERE s.iscomplete = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27548/15)

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch! I'll apparently have to learn myself some `APPLY`...

Comment: apply in this case is simply equivalent to left join, and put the apply's where to the join's on

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I think this is just what the OP did ... `ON cs.state = st.ID and st.iscomplete = 0`